# jQuery animate() event doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm developing a hotsite, where have balls falling from the top of the window to the bottom. You can see here: xxxxx

This animation works okay on all modern browsers. The hotsite is finished, btw.

The unique problem is on the Internet Explorer < 9, where the function to animate the balls to bottom don't work. The IE simplely don't call this, stopping all the script before your call.

The function is:

```
function bolaQueda1(bola, altura, tempo, esquerda) {
                esquerda = $(bola).css('left');
                $(bola).animate({
                    left: esquerda + '%',
                    top: altura + '%'
                }, tempo, "easeOutQuad");
                $(bola).attr('data-destino',altura);
                $(bola).attr('data-tempo',tempo);
            }
```

Anyone knows what is the problem?

very thx. :)

Comment: hmmm when animating any attribute of an element in IE, you need to make sure that in your CSS there is a starting point for the attribute you are going to alter. If you DO NOT put in a left & top starting position IE will eventually does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set an inicial position of the element that you are going to move. Maybe setting the "top" and "left" (your case I think).

```
.ball{
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I solved the problem. The var "esquerda" returns: value + 'px', in string. Solved! =)